# Not logging in with requests.session()

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I used requests library to log in to a website. I tried with scrapy, it is working fine. but when i try with requests, it is not working. I am getting the content of main page but not the page after logging in. when i print the url after post() method, i am not getting correct url. The code is below

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("http://collegekart.in/login")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
token=soup.find("meta",{"name":"csrf-token"})
print(token)
tok=token['content']
print(tok)
s=requests.session()
login={"username":'fdgdgfdgdfgdfg@gmail.com',"password":'dgfdgdfgfdgdfgd',"csrf-token":tok}
s.post("http://collegekart.in/login",data=login)
t=s.get("http://collegekart.in/users")
print(t.url)
sop=BeautifulSoup(t.content,"html.parser")
print(sop.prettify())
```

I am getting the output content of "collegekart.in" instead of "collegekart.in/users.

Comment: 'password':'hanfenghanfeng','username':'zerqqr1@iydhp.com' use these credentials. then collegekart.in/users will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go. You have done lots of unnecessary stuffs to do a simple task. However, when you get logged in, you can find that webpage displaying some items. I've scraped the title as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload={

'utf8':'✓',
'username':'zerqqr1@iydhp.com',
'password':'hanfenghanfeng'
}

res = requests.get("http://collegekart.in/access/attempt_login?",headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'},params=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(item.text)
```

Partial output from populated results:

```
Enriching Speakjng and Writing Skills
Engineering Chemistry 16th edition 
A Textbook of Engineering Physics
```

Comment: why didnt post() method work? post() is meant for that right.

Comment: Before doing such things, you should get a through knowledge on how any webpage responds and you can observe that using any developer tools. However, i think my answer serves your purpose so don't forget to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Open any webpage then right click on it you will notice few options including `inspect element`.Choose to select that then you will notice different tabs there out of which select `network tab` and then select `xhr` tab and sometimes `all` tab. Then reload the page and see the activities. Thanks.

Comment: Thanq so much for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

U can simply use get() method. In that use params attribute for login credentials.